# How to alter HTML file's text form a Java class

Tags: java, html

Is it possible to edit a HTML file directly from a Java class? For example, if I know exactly which row to alter, is there a Java method that will allow this? If so, then how? Thanks for your responses...

Comment: what kind of editing? replacing a token?

Answer (score 0):

An html file is just a text file.  You can edit text files but this is usually done by editing an in-memory version and then writing that edited version out, replacing the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way of doing it would be with the help of [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). [On their site](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file) you can find documentation how to do it